# Login Session - Activities

Tags: android, session

I have a login in my application. I want to know the best way to set a global session or equivalent that I can refer to from any activity so that they will know if a user is logged in. Also, so that other activities can get the user id to do database transactions.

I don't want to use putExtra() as I will have to do it for every Intent I build across the application.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can create an Application class which can be used as a global state holder.

Here's some sample code:

```
public class SampleApplication extends Application {

    private static String username;
    private static String password;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        username="";
        password="";
    }

    public static String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public static void setUsername(String username) {
        SampleApplication.username = username;
    }

    public static String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public static void setPassword(String password) {
        SampleApplication.password = password;
    }

}
```

After declaring static methods and variables, you should define your application class in your AndroidManifest.xml. Use the `android:name` attribute of the `application` tag in order to define your class name.

Here's some more sample code:

```
<application 
    android:name=".SampleApplication"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".SampleApp"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

Your application class will share all the life cycle events as that of Activity and will get destroyed when the application exits.

You can access your application variables with static getters and setters from any activity or service:

```
SampleApplication.setUsername("");
String currentUserName=SampleApplication.getUsername();
SampleApplication.setPassword("");
String currentPassword=SampleApplication.getPassword();
```

---

You can also, rather than going for singleton class, opt for the normal class of Application

Alternative to the same example:

```
public class SampleApplication extends Application {

    private String username;
    private String password;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        username="";
        password="";
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        SampleApplication.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        SampleApplication.password = password;
    }

}
```

You can access these with:

```
((SampleApplication)getApplication()).getUsername();
```

Comment: i have two applications in my Manifest file now.. is that ok ? http://pastebin.com/N8CGmFkt

Comment: No it certainly will not work, You cannot create to launchers and to application I have posted the code edit in you pastebin,

Comment: when u edit the pastebin it gives a new url :( i cant see ur edit

Comment: Oh sorry about that :( I didn't know about pastebin's this behavior, you marked my answer accepted. Did it work ?

Comment: Why you just dont create a singleton with the variables and getters/setters that you need? Activity has no sense in this case.