# Xamarin Android Global Session Variables - Error No constructor found (System.IntPtr, Android.Runtime.JniHandleOwnership)

Tags: variables, session, xamarin, xamarin.android, global

I'm working with Xamarin Android on Xamarin Studio 5.5.3, Im trying to create a global session state using the sample on this link:

[Login Session - Activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4534081/login-session-activities)
My code is pretty similar as the one on the link.
My Application Class:

```
namespace MyApp.Library.Droid
{
    public class SessionApplication : Application
    {
        private static int _userID;
        private static string _email;
        private static string _firstName;
        private static string _lastName;


        public override void OnCreate() {   
            base.OnCreate();
            _userID=0;
            _email=null;
            _firstName = null;
            _lastName = null;

        }

        public static int UserID
        {
            get { retu`enter code here`rn _userID; }
            set { _userID=value; }
        }

        public static string Email
        {
            get { return _email; }
            set { _email=value; }
        }

        public static string FirstName
        {
            get { return _firstName; }
            set { _firstName=value; }
        }

        public static string LastName
        {
            get { return _lastName; }
            set { _lastName=value; }
        }




    }
}
```

My Android Manifest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
        android:versionCode="1" 
        android:versionName="1.0" 
        package="myapp.ui.droid">

        <uses-sdk />

        <application android:label="myapp.ui.droid" android:name="myapp.library.droid.SessionApplication">

        </application>

    </manifest>
```

my code compiles but then it runs throws this exception.
[MonoDroid] UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:
[MonoDroid] System.NotSupportedException: Unable to activate instance of type MyApp.Library.Droid.SessionApplication from native handle a2600019 ---> 
    System.MissingMethodException: No constructor found for MyApp.Library.Droid.SessionApplication::.ctor(System.IntPtr, Android.Runtime.JniHandleOwnership) ---> 
    Java.Interop.JavaLocationException: Exception of type 'Java.Interop.JavaLocationException' was thrown.

I'll appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Congratulations, you've found one of the few cases where you need to provide an explicit constructor that handles when a Java object is exposed to managed (Mono) code.

From the docs:

> There are two scenarios in which the (IntPtr, JniHandleOwnership) constructor must be manually provided on a Managed Callable Wrapper subclass:
>
> 1 - Android.App.Application is subclassed. Application is special; the default Applicaton constructor will never be invoked, and the (IntPtr, JniHandleOwnership) constructor must instead be provided .
> Virtual method invocation from a base class constructor.

To fix this, provide a constructor with the `(IntPtr handle, JniHandleOwnership transfer)` signature.

```
[Application]
public class SessionApplication : Application
{
    public SessionApplication(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer)
        :base(javaReference, transfer)
    {
    }

    // ...
}
```

Some background reading:

- [Android Callable Wrappers](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/java_integration_overview/android_callable_wrappers/)
- [Xamarin.Android Architecture](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/under_the_hood/architecture/) (See *Java Activation* specifically).