# saving password in device memory in android

Tags: android, saving-data

I am creating an application which connects to the server using username/password and I would like to enable the option "Save password" so the user wouldn't have to type the password each time the application starts.
Can any one please tell me how to do this??
thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3039137/maintain-cookie-session-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to save data, you can look here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

But beware to save the password unencrypted. Save it encrypted and create a way you can check using the already encrypted password.

Answer (score 2):

In such a case you would use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)
Cheers!