# Android Session getting lost in IBM Websphere Server

Tags: android, session, tomcat, websphere

Whenever i hit the login page from an android device , a session has to be created and maintained until the user hits log out button.. But there seem to be a weird problem with IBM Websphere Servers .. i am able to login successfully but when i try to request some other data the session is getting lost from the server ,  this is not the case with server running on Apache TomCat .. also in iOS Devices its working fine !

Example  : 
 1. user logs in ->  creates a session for this user
 2. Android App hits the server continously with 1 sec interval 
 3. user logs out -> user is loggged out successfully

this flow is going proper in case of Apache TomCat , but in case of Websphere at step 2 .. the session is getting lost , because of which the user cant even log out

what could be the issue ? is there something i could be missing on server side ? or is it websphere has compatibility issue ?

Comment: Are you doing this from Chrome on Android? From within a WebView in your custom application? Are authenticated sessions working on other devices or platforms? Are you getting any errors in your logs?

Comment: its a custom android app without webview because all i need is a set of data(like strings) which server will give me and I am making request to server using httpclient...everything works fine with Apache Tomcat ,but when i switch to IBM Websphere ..in error log i see,the session goes null .. series of events ->
1. My app hits login page -> server replies success 
2. My app hits data page - > server replies with appropriate data on 1st Hit 
3. My app hits data page 2nd time - > here i get session null in Websphere, In iOS Devices everything works fine for both Apache as well as IBM Websphere

Comment: How are you handling the session information? Are you preserving your cookie between calls? See this other SO for implementation/reasoning: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6454516/940217

Comment: I have implemented in same manner .. still no luck with WebSphere .. session handling goes fine with Apache Tomcat .. also when i compared the response header that i get from tomcat with that of websphere .. the only difference i noticed is, in case of websphere there is ":-1" appended in JSESSIONID

Comment: -1 shouldn't be the issue, if you are comparing response header - is the sesssion ID for series of events? You wrote about login, are you using and provides security with WebSphere or is it your custom solution? Do you have one server or farm/cluster and doing any load balancing?

Comment: I meant, if the session id is changing during the series of events or is the same?

Comment: Gas,Kyle Thanks guys for your support.. i managed to solve the problem ... this problem exists because of Android and one important settings which has to be made in  Websphere

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue needs to be solved in 2 parts

1. Android Side

   Android HttpPost by default doesn't send necessary headers , so we need to add headers explicitly , of which the most important is JSESSIONID when your dealing with session management for android with Websphere Servers  .. all you got to do is get the JESSIONID from Server Reponse and attach it to any further request that you make to the server .
2. Websphere

Websphere needs to be set with important property , which can be achieved by following steps :

a. Open the administrative console.

b. Select Servers > Application Servers > Server_Name > Server
Infrastructure > Java and Process Management > Process Definition > Java Virtual Machine > Custom Properties > New.

c. Add a new Custom Property for the JVM to reuse the sessionId:
System Property Name: HttpSessionIdReuse System Property Value: true

d. Save your changes and restart the Application Server.