# JSESSIONID=0000fWm58im_RcpQXmWI8LlDdvg:-1 what does ":-1" resembles to?

Tags: android, session, servlets, websphere, jsessionid

I am trying to solve android session problem which i am facing with IBM Websphere server and when i logged response headers , JSESSIONID has ":-1" appended to it .What does ":-1" mean ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The part of the session cookie after `:` refers to the server cloneID or partitionID (in case of memory to memory session replication). It is used by WebSphere plugin to provide session affinity and route request to specific server holding session data. If session affinity is not required, then you can remove cloneId from `plugin-cfg.xml` and requests will be simply load balanced among servers.

`-1` says that you don't have cloneID set in the `plugin-cfg.xml` file or your server doesn't have cloneID set. This is usual in case of single server deployments (not clustered).

Comment: but when i logged response from iOS Device .. then it is working fine on iOS Device  ... also there is no ":-1" appended to JSESSIONID ..i am confused .. why is it happening only in case of Android Device ..

Comment: @Prathameshsawant I'm accessing web apps via browser on desktop (not mobile) and there is :-1, so this is rather iOS issue that there is no -1 there. What session problems are you observing on Android?

Comment: my post on stackoverflow - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28582049/android-session-getting-lost-in-ibm-websphere-server